# Raising a scalar to power of elements of a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I want to compute the following using numpy:

```
density = 1.474085291*(0.9998541833**h)
```

where `h` is a `1*12 matrix`.  I'd want the base as 0.9998541833 and powers (exponents) to be elements of the matrix `h`.
I have tried  [numpy.power](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.power.html) documentation, but can't find a solution.

Comment: You should show the error.  If `h` is regular numpy array, your code should work.  It's only when `h` is `np.matrix` that `**` has problems.  But `np.power(.99, h)` still works.  This is yet another reason to avoid `np.matrix` if you don't really need it.

Comment: The problem with `np.matrix` is that it redefines `**` (`__pow__`) to be a matrix power operator, `np.linalg.matrix_power`.  as in `np.matrix(eye(3))**4`.  Likewise `*` is redefined to be matrix multiplication (like `np.dot`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
base = 0.9998541833
density = 1.474085291 * np.array(base)**h
```

Comment: `np.array(base) ** h` should be enough.

Comment: @hpaulj, wouldn't a full array of h.shape be created under the hood? Would there be some difference in performance? Correct me if I am wrong, but I guess base**h is just syntactic sugar.

Comment: With broadcasting a full array of `h.shape` isn't necessary. The `base` is replicated in a way that doesn't require copies.  `base**h` gets translated into `base.__pow__(h)`.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty straightforward: you already seem to have the code in place.  Just form your array `h`, and your'e ready to go:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> h = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> h
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> density = 1.474085291*(0.9998541833**h)
>>> density
array([ 1.47387034,  1.47365543,  1.47344055,  1.47322569,  1.47301087,
        1.47279608])
```

Comment: what if 'h' is defined as np.matrix ?

Comment: @Ehsan I suggest to change the solution to this one. There is no need to use the `full` function here. Also I recommend read about numpy broadcasting.